# Euler-Maclaurin formula for path integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, renormalization, path-integral, mathematics

Is there a corresponding Euler-Maclaurin formula for path integral when we divide the path integral into discrete lattice?

[image]

What is the error correction when we divide the space into lattice of length scale "a"?

Comment: Hi, you can typeset equations here by enclosing your latex commands in dollar signs. If you can, please replace your image with a typeset equation

Comment: I just answered this after class! Grin :) We'll see if anyone does better than me....